# how to remove a page that was made private from google search results?

Tags: wordpress, google-search

I have a thank you page that I made private, it only appears when clicking on a submit button, but I don't know why it appears first on search results when I google site:mywebsite, I made it private but still appears but as a 404 error page.
How can I delete it permanantly from search results?

PS: without using the robots.txt.

Comment: Without robots.txt is not possible to hide page URLs in google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it but submitting a request to take it off in google search console, and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).